# How to use conditional formatting to color cells if the value of that cell is in another list in another sheet

Tags: google-sheets

I have 1 list of all members (sheet1)

[image: sheet1]

And another list in another sheet (sheet2) where their names can come up multiple times

[image: sheet2]

My question now is, how do i use conditional formatting to check if the names in Sheet 2 are also in the list of Sheet 1 (by coloring in those who are not in the list of sheet 1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't reference other sheets when using conditional format by default, but there is a workaround (using `INDIRECT`).

#### Custom Formula:

- `=IF(A:A<>"", IFNA(NOT(MATCH(A:A,INDIRECT("Sheet1!A:A"),0)), TRUE), FALSE)`

#### Output:

[image: output]

#### Conditional Format:

[image: format]